Study the pointwise convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{1+(x-1)^2 n^3}, x \in \mathbb{R}$.
I was studying Real Analysis and I was doing the following exercise. Study the pointwise convergence of the series of functions $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{1 + (x-1)^2 n^3}, x \in \mathbb{R}.$
I'm not sure if what I can use the comparison test like I used, but here is what I did.
Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be fixed.
Given that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(x-1)^2 \geq 0, \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}$, the given series is a series of positive terms.
For $x=1$ we have the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n$, which is divergent because $n \longrightarrow +\infty \neq 0$.
For $x \neq 1$, note that $1+(x-1)^2 n^3 \geq (x-1)^2 n^3$. Thus,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{1+(x-1)^2 n^3} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(x-1)^2 n^3}=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$.
The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent because $2 > 1$, therefore, $\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent.
$\therefore$ By the comparison test, we can conclude that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{1+(x-1)^2 n^3}$ is convergent for $x \neq 1.$
$\therefore$ The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{1+(x-1)^2 n^3}$ converges pointwise in $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$ and diverges in $x=1$.

Your answer is correct and neat. No need to fret.

Using the Euler-Maclaurin' summation formula, at $x\to1$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac n{1+(x-1)^2 n^3}=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3},\frac1{|x-1|^{4/3}}-\frac 1{12}+o\big(|x-1|\big)$$

@geetha290krm Thank you for your answer!

@Svyatoslav I haven't learned about that yet, but that's pretty cool. Thank you!
